# My MVC 5 application on load goes at the bottom after a second

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

I have mvc 5 web application it was working fine. But suddenly after some time when I run my application on any browser, if the page is longer than the screen it goes down on load.

The whole thing is on local.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

I installed an application from nuget package manager named "***Template 10***". That application was troubling mine one.

On uninstalling that app, problem got solved.